# if the checkbox is checked then radio disabled = false and not checked then the radio is disabled = true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

I have a form there contains one checkbox and one radio button (disabled=true). when checkbox checked then disabled radio button is false and when checkbox unchecked then radio button is disabled

and number 0 in id="rp0" get from loop or side server

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rp0" value="1011000646">

<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" id="trx0" value="0">
```

```
let temp = [];
 function prepAcc() {
        $("#tableAcc").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        $.ajax({
          url: urlAjax + $("#companyId").val(),
          async: true,
          success: function (result) {
            console.log("list acc result: " + result + ", type: " + (typeof result));
            console.log(result);
            temp.push(result); // temp obj

            var s = "";
            $.each(result.data, function (index, obj) {


              // let check = true
              //   < input disabled = { check? disabled: enabled } >

              $("#tableAcc").find('tbody')
                .append($('<tr>')
                  .append($('<td>').append(obj.cif))
                  .append($('<td>').append(obj.accNumber))
                  .append($('<td>').append(obj.accName))
                  .append($('<td>').append(obj.accCategoryName))
                  .append($('<td>').append($('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
                    .attr('id', 'rp' + index)
                    .attr('value', obj.accNumber)
                  ))
                  .append($('<td>').append($('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'radio')
                    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                    .attr('id', 'trx' + index)
                    .attr('value', 0)
                  ))
                );
              if (index > 0)
                s += "|";
              s += obj.accId;
            });
            $("#allAccString").val(s);
          },
          error: function (xhr) {
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
          }
        });

        ajdTrx();
      }
```

[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP79A.png)

The problem is when the checkbox is unchecked the radio is not disabled=false and it doesn't go into the for loop or map. I do like this

[red block is temp with temp obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLHn.png)

```
function ajdTrx() {
        for (let index = 0; index < temp.length; index++) {
          console.log('IN LOOP');
          let checker = document.getElementById('rp' + index);
          let sendbtn = document.getElementById('trx' + index);

          checker.onchange = function () {
            if (this.checked) {
              sendbtn.disabled = false;
            } else {
              sendbtn.disabled = true;
            }
          }
        }

        // temp.map((data, index) => {
        //   console.log('IN MAP');
        //   let checker = document.getElementById('rp' + index);
        //   let sendbtn = document.getElementById('trx' + index);
        //   checker.onchange = function () {
        //     if (this.checked) {
        //       sendbtn.disabled = false;
        //     } else {
        //       sendbtn.disabled = true;
        //     }
        //   }
        // });
        // var gf = $("input[id='rp']:checked").val();
        // console.log('TRX: ' + gf);


        console.log('TRX: ');
        console.log(temp);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not going inside for loop because there is no data in temp array at the time  `ajdTrx();` is called. Move `ajdTrx();` call inside the success callback and pass the result array as parameter to it. Apart from that other code seems to be working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-f32id2?file=index.js